MS Edge shows all open SharePoint tabs as separate windows on main taskbar
My edge started showing each tab of any window on any screen as separate window button on my main monitor taskbar. This only happens with SharePoint site tabs and certain types of files when open in browser. Below screenshot shows my main taskbar when I have 1 Edge window open on 2nd screen with 2 SharePoint tabs and 1 pdf file.

Windows 10, Edge Version 125.0.2535.67 (Official build) (64-bit), Nothing in taskbar or edge settings effects this behaviour.
